# Is it the integer rounding rules decides % operation's difference between C++, python3 and python2.7?

Tags: c++

I was reading *C++ Primer 5th*. When it comes to % operator, I was puzzled by the result **-21%4=-1**.

1. At first, I did some research and found that what we commonly use is **Euclidean division** in Number Theory, which requires remainder **r>0**. So neither of Python and C++ is implemented in that way. They use something else and that's fine as long as the quotient and remainder are unique.
2. Then I found out that in python2.7 **-21/4=-6** while **-(21/4)=-5**, `-21/4==-(21/4) //False`, but in python3 it gives float numbers without rounding so it's `True`. So I noticed that py2.7 is rounding towards negative infinity while C++ is rounding towards 0. Then I came up this deduction:

   We have **int** -> need **rounding rules** when it can't divide exactly:

   1. some rounding towards negative infinity -> (result in)remainder's sign is the same with divisor
   2. some rounding towards zero -> (result in)r's sign is the same with dividend

So I think it is the different rounding rules cause the different result of remainder, is it true? And if it's true, then why we would have the **rounding towards negative infinity** design at first? (Because it would cause the problem of `-21/4==-(21/4) //False`). Is it a somehow historical problem or sth else?

I don't think it's a duplicated question. I've read the old post. But it seems the cause and effect is that the rounding rules decides the different result and I am asking if it is true. And why python2.7 rounds towards negative infinity coz I think it's a bad choice.

Comment: @Jarod42 ya, sorry, mistyping.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I've read this already. But I think some answers are wrong about so-called 'true' modulo operation and I wanna know if there's cause and effect between the rounding rules and different remainder result.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to C++11 the behavior of the remainder operator `%` was implementation defined if one of the arguments was negative.

Since then, the result *must* be closest negative number possible to zero if the first argument is negative.

The mathematical cousin - the *modulus* - would set `-21` modulo `4` to be `3`. What the C++ standard insists is that the mathematical result has `4` subtracted from it to return the required negative.

Comment: -21/4=-6 in Python is correct. I tried it

Comment: @ThomasSablik: Sorry, I'm a turkey. For some reason I misread `/` in that expression. Coffee time.